# Finding the parent of an observableArray

Tags: drag-and-drop, knockout.js

I am trying to convert my project over to use Ryan Niemeyer's drag and drop plugin (http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html).

When an item is dragged to another group I need to set a property of the dragged item based on **the object that contains the observableArray it is being dragged in to**.

I have a viewModel along the lines of:

- viewModel

  - TopLevelObject

    - Children (an observableArray)

      - Child A whose **parent property is set to TopLevelObject**
      - Child B whose **parent property is set to TopLevelObject**

        - Children of Child B (an observableArray)

          - Child X whose **parent property is set to Child B**
          - Child Y whose **parent property is set to Child B**

It is the parent property that I need to set. I have access to `arg.targetParent` which is the 'Children' observableArray in the example above. So I think the solution would look something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.afterMove = function(arg) {
    // how do I get the object that contains the arg.targetParent observable array??
    var parentOfTargetObservableArray = /* the containing object of arg.targetParent */                    
    arg.item.MyParent(parentOfTargetObservableArray);
}
```

**Given an observableArray in isolation, is there a way to find the object that contains it???**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly get to the parent of the observableArray without leaving further clues on the objects.  There are a couple of ways that you could do this:

-Add the parent as a property of your observableArray.  observableArrays are functions, which are objects, so you can actually add properties to them like:

```
this.Children = ko.observableArray(...);
this.Children.parent = parent;
```

Then you can simply read the `parent` property off of `arg.targetParent`

-otherwise, if you can get access to the higher level object (perhaps it is already global), then you can loop through the top level children and check if `topLevelChild.Children === arg.targetParent`

If you need code samples, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for this, Ryan. This confirmed that I can't easily get to the parent (thought I was going mad!). I like the "this.Children.parent = parent;" technique although in my specific case I may be tempted to extend the sortable plugin to include the additional info on the arg object that I need (eg. something like: "targetParentContainer: ko.dataFor(ui.item.parent()[0]);").

Comment: I might consider exposing the `ui` and `event` arguments to the callbacks.

Comment: Good idea. That would certainly cover more cases where the user wants to call functions such as ko.dataFor(), .data(), .parent() etc.

Comment: I went to make changes to pass the `event` and `ui` objects to the callbacks and found that I was already passing them as the 2nd and 3rd arguments.  I updated the docs to clarify.

Comment: Excellent. These are very useful parameters to have. Thanks Ryan. For other SO users the docs are at https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable#readme

Answer (score 0):

Knockout provides a function that allows you to give it a DOM element, and it will find the closest knockout parent.  The function is called `ko.dataFor()`.  You can see an example here: [Using unobtrusive event handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html)

Here's a quick hack of your code untested but demonstrating the use of dataFor:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.afterMove = function(arg) {
    var parentOfTargetObservableArray = ko.dataFor(arg.targetParent);
    arg.item.MyParent(parentOfTargetObservableArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, soniiic. However, arg.targetParent is a observableArray, not a dom element so ko.dataFor won't work.